# How do I make NFS automounted volumes visible in Finder?

Tags: macos, finder, mount, automount, autofs

How do I make NFS automounted volumes visible in Finder or, in other words, have opposite effect to default option **nobrowse**?

From mount manpage

> ```
> nobrowse
>      This option indicates that the mount point should not be visible via the GUI
>      (i.e., appear on the Desktop as a separate volume).
> ```

This is edited *mount* command output from Mac Pro

```
mac-pro:~ shpokas$ mount
/dev/disk0s2 on / (hfs, local, journaled)
devfs on /dev (devfs, local, nobrowse)
map -hosts on /net (autofs, nosuid, automounted, nobrowse)
map auto_home on /home (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
map autofs_nfs on /Volumes/nfs (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
/dev/disk1s2 on /Volumes/VFS HDD 0122 (hfs, local, nodev, nosuid, journaled, noowners)
varaklani:/faili on /Volumes/nfs/faili (nfs, nodev, nosuid, automounted, **nobrowse**)
```

Comment: I would have assumed that they would just show up as soon as they mounted...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Finder:Preferences:General:Show these items on the desktop and check Connected servers?

That normally works for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you edit `/etc/autofs.conf` and uncomment / add the line / set to FALSE

```
AUTOMOUNTD_NOBROWSE=FALSE
```

Then theoretically automount should mount the volume and set it to be visible in Finder... however I believe there is a bug in macOS which currently means this file is not read / the setting is ignored :(